# Precondition and class containment

Tags: preconditions, post-conditions

Assume I have the following class:

```
public class Player {
private Board board;
private int roundsPlayed = 0;

public void play() {
    while (board.isAvailable() && roundsPlayed < 10) {
        // playing on the board
        roundsPlayed++;
    }
}
}
```

What is the Pre/Post condition of my `Player`'s `play()` method ?

My answer for the precondition would be centered around the `roundsPlayed` variable,

However I'm wondering whether or not my pre/post condition should include the fact that I'm using the `Board` and probably its variables in my method

Should my pre / post condition consider `Board` in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a precondition that `board` is not `null`.